# Плагин для синхронизации товаров woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Всем привет! Создаю плагин для синхронизации с woocommerce. Столкнулся с трудностью записи данных с формы в БД. Сразу говор что первый раз пишу плагин для wordpress. Как записывать данные уже знаю. Любые ссылки на туториалы и документацию приветствуются) А вот отправить данные с формы которая создана как в примере ниже затрудняюсь. Добавляю вот такой таб для woocommerce: 
Сналача сам таб:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_sections_api','add_subtab' );
function add_subtab( $settings_tabs ) {
        $settings_tabs['custom_settings'] = __( 'Custom Settings', 'woocommerce-custom-settings-tab' );
        return $settings_tabs;
}
```

Дальше настройки для него:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_settings_api', 'add_subtab_settings', 10, 2 );
function add_subtab_settings( $settings ) {
        $current_section = (isset($_GET['section']) && !empty($_GET['section']))? $_GET['section']:'';
        if ( $current_section == 'custom_settings' ) {
                $custom_settings = array();
                $custom_settings[] = array( 'name' => __( 'Custom Settings', 'text-domain' ),
                                                                     'type' => 'title',
                                                                     'desc' => __( 'The following options are used to ...', 'text-domain' ),
                                                                     'id' => 'custom_settings'
                                                                    );

                $custom_settings[] = array(
                                                                        'name'     => __( 'Field 1', 'text-domain' ),
                                                                        'id'       => 'field_one',
                                                                        'type'     => 'text',
                                                                        'default'  => get_option('field_one'),

                                                                );

                $custom_settings[] = array( 'type' => 'sectionend', 'id' => 'test-options' );
                return $custom_settings;
        } else {
                // If not, return the standard settings
                return $settings;
        }
}
```

Создается такая форма:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну и вопросы, как добавить значения в value инпута с БД. - для этого у меня есть фукнция уже вывода готовой строки и как записывать в БД value который вводим?)